# Access Vuex Store from a js file

Tags: javascript, import, vuex, action

I have this **Read.js** that reads an image. And I want to save the content of the image (in bytes) into a vuex Store.

I'm trying to import the store into Read.js with:

```
import Store from "src/store/index";
```

After I read the bytes, I try to access the actions to save it to the state using:

```
Store.actions.A_updateImage(payload);
```

But i get that ".actions" is "Undefined".

This is the main store file that import the modules:

```
//src/store/index.js

    import Vue from 'vue'
    import Vuex from 'vuex'
    
    import My_store from './modules/My_store'
    
    Vue.use(Vuex)
    
    export default function (/* { ssrContext } */) {
      const Store = new Vuex.Store({
        modules: {
          My_store
        },

        strict: process.env.DEBUGGING
      })
    
      return Store
    }
```

This is the store module that has the action i want to use:

```
//src/store/modules/My_store.js

const state = {
  Image: {}
}
const mutations = {
  M_updateImage: (state, Image) => {
    state.Image = Image;     
  },  
}

const actions = {
    A_updateImage({ commit }, Image) {
        commit('M_updateImage', Image)
  }  
}

const getters = {
  getImage:(state) =>{
    return state.image
  }  

}

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions,
  state
}
```

**How can I import and call the action I need to use from the Read.js file?**

Thank you

Comment: It should be the other way around:  import the helper module into the store and call an action that uses it.

Comment: The way around I've found is to import the Read.js in s Vue component and from there parse (again) the object it returns to put the content in the store. It works, but I feel like doing almost the same thing twice.